# I have a problem with the rotation of the groups in three.js

Tags: three.js

My question is the following when I activate the rotation, the rotation is generated around the grandfather but not the father, how do I make the rotation around the father, which is aquaterraSystem, and not the grandfather, which is solSystem?

```
 const aquaterra = new Planet(1.5, 43, aquaterraImg );
    const aquaterraMesh = aquaterra.getMesh();
    let aquaterraSystem = new THREE.Group();
    let lunaSystem = new THREE.Group();

    aquaterraSystem.add(aquaterraMesh);
    const lunaaquaterra = new Planet(0.3, 46,  sol  );

    
    const lunaaquaterraMesh = lunaaquaterra.getMesh();
    lunaSystem.add(lunaaquaterraMesh);


    aquaterraSystem.add(lunaSystem);
   solarSystem.add(helionSystem,  aquaterraSystem,ZephyriaSystem );
    const lunaaquaterraRotation = new Rotation(lunaaquaterraMesh);//generates the rotation
export default class Rotation {
  constructor(planetMesh, showRotation = false) {
    this.planetPositionX = planetMesh.position.x;
    this.y = 0.25;
    this.z = 0.25;
    this.showRotation = showRotation;
  }

  getMesh() {
    if (this.mesh === undefined || this.mesh === null) {
      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(this.planetPositionX, 0.25, 0.25);
      const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
      this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      this.mesh.position.x = this.planetPositionX / 2;
      this.mesh.visible = this.showRotation;
    }
    return this.mesh;
  }
}// generates textures and rotation

        lunaSystemSystem.rotation.y += AQUATERRA_YEAR *1.6;
```